# What to call this graph showing icons for artists on a horizontal axis indicating number of unique words used?

Tags: data-visualization

What type of graph is this developer using?

[image: graph]

Copied from [here](http://rappers.mdaniels.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the [beeswarm](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/~eklund/beeswarm/) version of a [stripchart](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/plotting.html#strip-charts), with photos of the artists in place of dots.

Comment: Awesome. Beeswarm looks like the way to go. Now to implement this with matplotlib using pandas DataFrames!

Comment: The "closely-packed" criterion for a beeswarm does not seem to apply to the example. Accepting this (for the nonce) as an *intended* beeswarm gives us a novel example of a significant [lie factor](http://www.datavis.ca/gallery/lie-factor.php) :-).

Comment: @hanleyhansen: [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/) has a beeswarm plot function that works nicely with pandas DataFrames.

Comment: @hanleyhansen You're welcome. Be aware that seaborn doesn't support photo beeswarms, though. :)

Answer (score 7):

There is a single numeric axis against which values are plotted and there is some mix of stacking and jittering to separate points that might occlude or overlap each other. Short of the photos, which make the graph distinctive, I have come across the following names for broadly similar plots:

`barcode charts
beeswarm plots
circle plots
column scatter plot 
data distribution graph
dispersal graphs
dispersion diagrams
dit plots
dot array charts
dot charts
dot diagrams
dot histograms
dot patterns 
dot plots
instance chart 
line charts
line plots
linear plots
needle plots
number-line plots
one-axis data distribution graph
one-dimensional scatter plots
oneway graphs
oneway plots
point graphs
raster plots
strip charts
strip plots
stripe graph 
stripes plot
unidimensional scatter plots
univariate scatter plots
Wilkinson dot plots`

plus several variations of those running words together or using different hyphenation, which I am not quite crazy enough to collect.

Stata users might care to note that these are documented in the help for my `stripplot` command available from SSC.

Answer (score 4):

This is [a dot chart](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0034) with some non-random jittering for legibility.

It it not a [dot plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_plot_%28statistics%29), though there's some superficial similarity.

Comment: There is some superficial similarity, but I would say dot plots usually have many lines with only one or few dots per line.

Comment: @gung I think of dot plots as having a histogram-like component that is (or should be) mostly absent here. Judging by the responses here, that is probably not a widely shared view. I was hoping to point out that the artists just shy of 3,600 should be arrayed horizontally given their vocabulary size values, but their current position creates an illusion of a mass point that is unfortunate since this chart is not really a histogram.

Comment: Yeah, I think these names are ultimately somewhat subjective & even arbitrary. @NickCox's post documents some of that. I was just commenting that I wouldn't really call this a "dot plot", but it's a reasonable name nonetheless; I upvoted it anyway.